# How to set Listviewitem margins to use the Listviewitem's background color?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, styles

I am using alternating colors, and it works well, but by default I was getting white lines between the items, i.e. margins/padding, so I set them to 0, which makes it look like this:

[image]

But I want some margin between them, it's just when I have margin it looks like this:

[image]

How can I make it so that the white margins use the background of the listviewitem?

Here is the xaml code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1e1e1e"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3c3c3c"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <ListView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Coins}" Name="Tasks" Height="250" AlternationCount="2">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="25" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}">
                    
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="25" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Symbol" Width="90">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.Symbol}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Amount" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Unit Price" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Capital" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Profit" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="PNL %" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Day %" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Hour %" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Min %" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Lowest" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="90">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value.PriceDecimalDisplay}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Highest" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Vol BTC/h" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Net BTC/m" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value.X}"></GridViewColumn>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
</Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a `Border` instead of a Margin for your ListViewItem?
For example you could set your Border inside a `ControlTemplate`:

```
<Style x:Key="BorderedItem" TargetType="ListViewItem">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Border Name="Border" 
                BorderBrush="#1e1e1e" 
                BorderThickness="0,0,0,10">
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then you can set your Style in the ListView:

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource BorderedItem}" />
```

To change the `BorderBrush` color depending on your AlternationIndex you could bind it to a property and change it's state from your ViewModel.